# What does "I of knowledge" mean?

Tags: word-usage

In the preface of the [What is life?](http://whatislife.stanford.edu/LoCo_files/What-is-Life.pdf) book of Schrodinger, he said this in the first sentence

> A scientist is supposed to have a complete and thorough **I of knowledge**

What does *I of knowledge* mean? Did he mean *eye of knowledge*?

Comment: if *I* is something specific in science, we can migrate this question to [History of Science and Mathematics](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: 'Tain't specific to science- it's old-fashioned pseudo-scientific mumbo-jumbo taken from "psychology" or "philosophy" or whatever other polite moniker you'd like to hang on "sophistry".

Comment: @bobro do you have any proof?

Comment: You may see the quote from Jung I gave, and google "I and not-I" to see that it was indeed such a term. "Ego and id" are still with us, from another school of similar cast and vintage.

Comment: You can buy a whole book on it if you'd like, about Jungian theory, titled "The I and the Not-I" .http://www.amazon.com/The-Not-I-Mary-Esther-Harding/dp/0691017964

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's almost certainly based on a typo etc.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth do we have a policy for question about word usage but it turns out to be typo or bad scanning?

Comment: Yes. It's not about conventional English usage, so it's off-topic. (Some mistakes become accepted into usage, but this one is ridiculous.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ok, one vote from me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bad scanning.

It's:

> [What is Life?: With Mind and Matter and Autobiographical ...](https://books.google.ca/books?id=gdILAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA1&dq=%22A%20scientist%20is%20supposed%20to%20have%20a%20complete%20and%20thorough%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-L8eVfHnJZfbsATbtIHgAQ&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22A%20scientist%20is%20supposed%20to%20have%20a%20complete%20and%20thorough%22&f=false) -
>   Page 1 Erwin Schrodinger
>
> A scientist **is supposed to have a complete and thorough knowledge,
>   at first hand,** of some subjects and, therefore, is usually expected
>   not to write on any topic of which he is not a master. This is
>   regarded as a matter of noblesse oblige

Comment: Maybe this was the old usage that was edited out when the book you linked published? Because it's hard to mistake the "of" when scanning, I guess?

Comment: @Ooker It could have been a note in the margin that was OCRed when the page was scanned in.

Answer (score -1):

The I and the not-I are "philosophical" terms and concepts from the late 19th Century or early 20th Century. The I is reflective internal and the not-I external, projective, would be a fair summation, I'd say.

Here's a quote from Carl Jung, so you may judge for yourself:

"What is not-I, not masculine, is most probably feminine, and because the not-I is not felt is belonging to me, and therefore as outside me, the anima image is usually projected upon women".

I'm assuming the quote in the question is the original question here. It's looks like an error though, see the answer by Marius Hancu.

Comment: So what does *I of knowledge* mean if it is not bad scanning? I don't understand what is the internal of knowledge.

Comment: @Ooker - it would mean something along the lines of internalized and deeply understood knowledge, I think.

Comment: kind of complicated. I think bad scanning is a better answer though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, I think it's bad scanning! However, in my work (in the arts) I do run across such nutty sentences full of Jungian, Freudian, Lacanian, what have you, neologisms all the time.

Comment: Maybe artists prefer to have mumbo-jumbo? :P

Comment: Yer tellin' me, LOL.